# Unaddressed Reciepient NDR

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have an issue where a user is sending to a distribution list and that user is receiving an NDR back for an individual who is not a member of the distribution list.  Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if one of the members of the distribution list has a delegate set up on their mailbox that is disabled, especially if it was a meeting that was sent to the distribution list.

Comment: Is there an easy way to determine who that might be via powershell?